# Text object in matplotlib doesn't respond to zooming properly

Tags: python, matplotlib

.
Hello, everyone.

I recently try to add text object in my plot. But when I zoom into the text, the text size remains unchanged. What I want to have is that the text size will increase when I zoom in and will decrease when I zoom out.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.text('','', '',position=[0.5,0.5], text='Y', fontsize='xx-small' )
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks~

**Supplement-UTC+8 30/04/2013 9:40 AM**

Thanks for the suggestion from tcaswell. TextPath does achieve part of my purposes.

I found there is no documentation about textpath in official matplotlib website, so I view the source code to see what it does. Finally, I achieved a not excellent but satisfactory result as follows.

```
from matplotlib.textpath import TextPath
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib.path import Path

fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111)
tp1=TextPath((0.5,0.5), r'How do you turn this on?', size=1)
polygon=tp1.to_polygons()
for a in polygon:
    p1=patches.Polygon(a)
    ax1.add_patch(p1)
```

The not excellent part of this code is that it doesn't support rotation and export the text as filled polygon. Is there any easy way to rotate the text? Can I export the text as non-filled polygon?

Comment: The library is behaving as intended (text is rendered at a fixed font size relative to the absolute size off the figure).  To get what you want convert the text to a path and plot it by hand.

Comment: Can I do this by adjusting the tranform argument in axes.text? Moreover, is there any demonstration about how to transform text to path?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a Polygon instance, you can specify many keyword arguments, including setting `fill = False` (see details [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8T4Zw.png)):

```
from matplotlib.textpath import TextPath
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib.path import Path

fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.set_ylim(-1 , 3)
ax1.set_xlim(-3, 15)
tp1=TextPath((0.0,0.5), r'How do you turn this on?', size=1)
polygon=tp1.to_polygons()
for a in polygon:
    p1=patches.Polygon(a, fill=False)
    ax1.add_patch(p1)

plt.show()
```

[image: figure image]

Comment: With `TextPath` I can't figure out how to get wrapping. `TextPath` does not have the argument `wrap`. Any ideas on this?

Comment: "Is there any easy way to rotate the text?"

Its 2022, and I'm still stuck with the same problem. Do we have a way to create vertical text using TextPath? I have tried by adding a '\n" after each character, but its only entering a box character.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the question and the pre-work! My solution is just called by the command:

```
text_fixed_size(ax=ax, text=f'pos=(4,8), h=1', pos=(4,8), h=1, color=c)
```

and produces the orange output in the following (solid text and holes, like in 'o', not filled) picture. This solution also works for inverted axes. Height and width can be set independently, if needed.

[image]

**Code**

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def text_fixed_size(ax, text, pos, w=None, h=None, auto_trans=True, color='k'):

    assert not (w is None and h is None)

    tp = mpl.textpath.TextPath((0.0,0.0), text, size=1)
    x0, y0 = np.amin(np.array(tp.vertices), axis=0)
    x1, y1 = np.amax(np.array(tp.vertices), axis=0)
    hax = -np.subtract(*ax.get_xlim())
    wax = -np.subtract(*ax.get_ylim())

    if w is None:
        w = h / (y1 - y0) * ( x1 - x0)
    if h is None:
        h = w / (x1 - x0) * ( y1 - y0)
    if auto_trans:
        w *= np.sign(hax)
        h *= np.sign(wax)

    verts = []
    for vert in tp.vertices:
        vx = vert[0] * w / (x1 - x0) + pos[0]
        vy = vert[1] * h / (y1 - y0) + pos[1]
        verts += [ [vx, vy] ]
    verts = np.array(verts)

    tp = mpl.path.Path(verts, tp.codes)
    ax.add_patch(mpl.patches.PathPatch(tp, facecolor=color, lw=0))

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
axs = np.array(axs).T.flatten()

lims = np.array([[0, 15], [0,10]])
for aa, ax in enumerate(axs):
    d0 = int((-(aa%2)+.5)*2)
    d1 = int((-(aa//2)+.5)*2)
    l = np.array([lims[0, ::d0], lims[1, ::d1]])
    ax.set_xlim(l[0, 0], l[0, 1])
    ax.set_ylim(l[1, 0], l[1, 1])

for aa, ax in enumerate(axs):
    c = 'C0'
    text_fixed_size(ax=ax, text=f'pos=(6,3), w=5, h=1',
                    pos=(6,3), w=5, h=1, color=c)
    c = 'C1'
    text_fixed_size(ax=ax, text=f'pos=(4,8), h=1',
                    pos=(4,8), h=1, color=c)
    c = 'C2'
    text_fixed_size(ax=ax, text=f'pos=(8,1), w=5, auto_trans=False',
                    pos=(3,1), w=10, auto_trans=False, color=c)

plt.show()
```